# Write Output to Console in Middle of Process

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, I have an array `$folders` that stores the name of folders in a directory.

Some of these folders contain hundreds of thousands of files. Therefore, the following process takes a while to run:

`foreach($folder in $folders) {Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse -File | Select-Object Length,Extension, FullName | Export-Csv -Path .\myxlfile.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation; Write-Host "$folder complete"}`

Although I'm able to output to the console at the end of iterating through a folder, I would like to instead output after iterating through each **file**.

I've tried `foreach($folder in $folders) {Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse -File | Select-Object Length,Extension, FullName; Write-Host $count += 1 | Export-Csv -Path .\myxlfile.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation; Write-Host "$folder complete"}` but it doesn't have an effect.

My desired output is, if a folder has 300,000 iterables, to output to console `1 2 3 ... 299999 300000` so I know the objects are being written to Excel one by one.

Comment: this would fill your console with numbers, are you sure you want to do that? this would also affect your performance. the reason why your code is slow is because you're using `-Append` nothing more. You need to switch to a pipeline loop and put `Export-Csv` as the last statement of your pipeline

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon What would you suggest? Also, it is the last statement.

Comment: no, currently `Export-Csv` is inside your `foreach` loop :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Good point. I tried `foreach($folder in $folders) {Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse -File | Select-Object Length,Extension,FullName} Export-Csv -Path .\myxlfile.csv -NoTypeInformation` But that's giving me the wrong output.

Comment: try with the code in my answer, you will notice the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leverage the cmdlets [pipeline capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.3), let their [`process` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#process) do the work:

```
$folders | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File |
    Select-Object Length, Extension, FullName |
    Export-Csv .\myxlfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```